# Как добавить в post запрос form-data?

Tags: java, android, post, formdata

Как исправить код, чтобы корректно отправляло "form-data":

```
private static Request request = null;
private static OkHttpClient client= new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .cookieJar(new CookieJar() {
            private final HashMap<HttpUrl, List<Cookie>> cookieStore = new HashMap<>();

            @Override
            public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
                cookieStore.put(url, cookies);
            }

            @Override
            public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
                List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.get(url);
                return cookies != null ? cookies : new ArrayList<Cookie>();
            }
        }).build();
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("user_name", "значение-1")
                .add("user_pass", "значение-2")
                .build();

        request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://сайт.ru/")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        System.out.println(client
                .newCall(request)
                .execute().body().string());
```

Делаю точно такой же запрос через postman, но ответы сайта различаются. Может не правильно пишу в андройд или что-то пропускаю??
postman:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А запрос в коде postmana на java выглядит так:

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "------        
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"user_name\"\r\n\r\nЗначение-1\r\n------
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; 
name=\"user_pass\"\r\n\r\nЗначение2\r\n------
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--");
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://сайт.ru/").post(body).addHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----        
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW").addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded").addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache").addHeader("Postman-Token", "2c124ba6-7bef-772d-404d-8136f5166b45").build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

При отправке из postman MediaType = `multipart/form-data`, чтобы создать аналогичный запрос вручную, используйте [MultipartBody.Builder](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/MultipartBody.Builder.html):

```
RequestBody partFormBody = new FormBody.Builder()
    .add("user_name", "значение-1")
    .add("user_pass", "значение-2")
    .build();
RequestBody formBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
    .addPart(partFormBody)
    .build();
```

Comment: request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://сайт.ru/")
                    .post(formBody)
                    .build();     Вот такой код, но всё равно не работает.

Comment: @артемШеломенцев, обновил ответ - попробуйте так

Comment: Не получается, можно где нибудь посмотреть что именно отправляет postman и что отправляет android